# Convergence function of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {1\over{k^4e^{kt}}}$

Tags: power-series, exponential-function

Please help me evaluate to what time function $f(t)$ the following series converges:

$$ 
f(t)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {1\over{k^4e^{kt}}}\tag1
$$

where $t$ can not be infinite. By using Matlab, I plotted expression $(1)$ for $k_{max} = 100000$ and $t_{max} = 3$. I also plotted an approximation of form $f_a(t)= \Big({{1.08e^{\sqrt{1.08}\cdot t}}}\Big)^{-1}$. The solution seems to be close to the form $\Big({{Ce^{\sqrt{C}\cdot t}}}\Big)^{-1}$.

[image]

Comment: [$\operatorname{Li}_4(e^{-t})$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) (special function, no elementary closed form).

Comment: Wow, Matlab plot shows a direct match. Thank you @metamorphy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\sum_{k\ge1}1/k^4=\pi^4/90$ converges, we have that $$\mathrm{Li}_4(e^{-t})=\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{e^{-kt}}{k^4}$$
converges uniformly for $|e^{-t}|\le1$, implying $t\ge0$.